If I have an index with three columns, but I have two queries, one on only two columns and one on three columns - will both use the same index?
I have an object that has IsDeleted and RealmIntID as columns that will always be present in every query for that object (as well as some pagination params). We do not want to return soft deleted objects, and we do not want to return objects that are not in the realm.
There's another query as well, where I need to check IsDeleted, RealmIntID and the display name (for a search box type query). I want to properly index this as well. I'd like to avoid two indexes if possible, because I know each new index is another cut to my performance.
Would an index on [IsDeleted, RealmIntId, DisplayName] serve both queries? I assume the first query would just query the first two columns of the index, while the second query would use all three.

Is it often you'll need data from the table where it is soft deleted? If not, have you considered a filtered index? For example, if RealmIntId is the "main" filter, perhaps something like CREATE INDEX IX_YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable (RealmIntId) INCLUDE (DisplayName[<, Other Columns>]) WHERE IsDeleted = 0;

@ThomA Would a query that looked for isdeleted = 1 just not use that index? So if half my 1000-row table were deleted that index would only contain 500 items? Sounds pretty cool, I'll have to look at it, because no, we actually don't query on isdeleted except for exceptional circumstances.

A filtered index only includes rows that are within the filter. So yes, if your table contains 1,000 rows where 500 have the value 1 for IsDeleted and the other 500 the value 0, the index would only include the latter 500 rows. Then, if you used a query that had IsDeleted = 0 in it, that index might be used (if it's covering). If it doesn't include that clause, or it has IsDeleted = 1 the index would not be used.

Yes - an index is potentially used, if the "n left-most columns" are part of your criteria - here, once you're using the 2 left-most columns, once you're using all 3 - one index should be suitable for both those queries in this case

Try it and see?

There is this wonderful blog by Craig Freedman (link at bottom), which has some nice examples. Quoted relevant parts to avoid link rot
Also see this wonderful answers:
How important is the order of columns in indexes?
Single Column Indexes:
Suppose we have a single column index on a column “a”.  We can use this index to seek on these predicates:
a = 3.14
a > 100
a between 0 and 99
a like ‘abc%’
a in (2, 3, 5, 7)

Multi-column indexes:
Multi-column indexes are slightly more complex.  With a multi-column index, the order of the keys matters.  It determines the sort order of the index and it affects the set of seek predicates that SQL Server can evaluate using the index.
if we have an index on two columns, we can only use the index to satisfy a predicate on the second column if we have an equality predicate on the first column.  Even if we cannot use the index to satisfy the predicate on the second column, we may be able to use it on the first column.  In this case, we introduce a residual predicate for the predicate on the second column.  This is the same residual predicate that we use for scans.
Suppose we have a two column index on column “a” and “b”.
We can also use it to seek on these additional predicates:
a = 3.14 and b = ‘pi’
a = ‘xyzzy’ and b <= 0

We cannot use the index to seek on the next set of predicates as we cannot seek even on column a.  In these cases, we must use a different index (e.g., one where column b is the leading column) or we must use a scan with a residual predicate.
b = 0
a + 1 = 9 and b between 1 and 9
a like ‘%abc’ and b in (1, 3, 5)

Also please note, a bookmark lookup may cross the tipping point and it may lead to a scan
Now coming to your question "Would an index on [IsDeleted, RealmIntId, DisplayName] serve both queries?".
It depends on your query and columns in your select statement and if they are part of the index. Even if the columns in select, are part of the index, you can see above examples to see, what type of indexes suits a query.
My general rule of thumb is, if a query is more frequent and needs to be completed fast, I will create indexes. If the query is rare, I will not burden my table with additional indexes.
References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/seek-predicates
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/why-arent-those-nonclustered-indexes-being-used/

TL;DR Yes.
Your three-column index will support a query with a WHERE clause that mentions its first two columns. That's the way BTREE indexes work.
